# Count dates and compare them at the same time SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, datetime

I have several `datetime` columns. I need to calculate in SQL Server 2008 for each timestamp how many datetime stamps in the same column are smaller than each of datetime stamps.

For example: for `2016-05-01 14:24:000.00` in column `DateTime1` I need to calculate how many datetime values are smaller then it in `DateTime1` column.

I also need to know how many datetimestamps are smaller than a datetime stamp for the same record (in the same row) in column `DateTime2` and `3`.

```
DateTime1                   DateTime2                  DateTime3
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-05-01 13:24:000.00    2016-05-01 15:24:000.00   2016-05-01 16:20:000.00 
2016-05-01 13:30:000.00    2016-05-01 14:21:000.00   2016-05-01 15:10:000.00 
2016-05-01 14:24:000.00    2016-05-01 17:21:000.00   2016-05-01 18:10:000.00
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample results.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       rank() over (order by datetime1) as dt1_rank,
       rank() over (order by datetime2) as dt2_rank,
       rank() over (order by datetime3) as dt3_rank
from t ;
```

Depending on how you want to treat tied values, you might actually want `dense_rank()`.  Also, you might want to subtract 1 from the ranking value.

Answer (score 0):

Assume I have a Table name [TestTB] has 3 columns DateTime1,DateTime2,DateTime3 . 
I said CountSmallerDateTime1 as  "how many datetime values are smaller then it in DateTime1 column"
I said CountSmallerDateTime2 as "how many datetimestamps are smaller than a datetime stamp for the same record (in the same row) in column DateTime2" , Similarity , CountSmallerDateTime3 for DateTime3 .
Then I have a query for your request :

```
SELECT [DateTime1]
  ,[DateTime2]
  ,[DateTime3]
  ,(SELECT COUNT(1) 
    FROM [TestTB] Sub 
    WHERE TB.[DateTime1] >Sub.[DateTime1]) AS CountSmallerDateTime1
  ,(
    CASE WHEN TB.[DateTime2] > TB.[DateTime1]  AND TB.[DateTime2] > TB.[DateTime3] THEN 
        2
        WHEN ( (TB.[DateTime2] <= TB.[DateTime1]  AND TB.[DateTime2] > TB.[DateTime3])
            OR (TB.[DateTime2] > TB.[DateTime1]  AND TB.[DateTime2] <= TB.[DateTime3])) THEN
            1
    ELSE
        0
    END
  ) AS CountSmallerDateTime2,
  (
    CASE WHEN TB.[DateTime3] > TB.[DateTime1]  AND TB.[DateTime3] > TB.[DateTime2] THEN 
        2
        WHEN ( (TB.[DateTime3] <= TB.[DateTime1]  AND TB.[DateTime3] > TB.[DateTime2])
            OR (TB.[DateTime3] > TB.[DateTime1]  AND TB.[DateTime3] <= TB.[DateTime2])) THEN
            1
    ELSE
        0
    END
  ) AS CountSmallerDateTime3 FROM [TestTB] TB
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE(DATE1, DATE2, DATE3,RN)
AS
(
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME , '2016-05-01 13:24:000.00'),   CONVERT(DATETIME,'2016-05-01 15:24:000.00'), CONVERT(DATETIME,'2016-05-01 16:20:000.00'),1 
UNION ALL
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME , '2016-05-01 13:30:000.00'),   CONVERT(DATETIME,'2016-05-01 14:21:000.00'), CONVERT(DATETIME,'2016-05-01 15:10:000.00'),2 
UNION ALL
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME , '2016-05-01 14:24:000.00'),   CONVERT(DATETIME,'2016-05-01 17:21:000.00'), CONVERT(DATETIME,'2016-05-01 18:10:000.00'),3
)
SELECT     RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DATE1) -1 AS SAME_COLUMN_DATE1 
         , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DATE2) -1 AS SAME_COLUMN_DATE2
         , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DATE3) -1 AS SAME_COLUMN_DATE3  

         , CASE WHEN RN=1 AND DATE1< DATE2 AND DATE1<DATE3 THEN 0
                WHEN RN=1 AND DATE1< DATE2 AND DATE1>DATE3 THEN 1
                WHEN RN=1 AND DATE1> DATE2 AND DATE1<DATE3 THEN 1
                ELSE 2
                SAME_ROW_1

         , CASE WHEN RN=2 AND DATE2< DATE1 AND DATE2<DATE3 THEN 0
                WHEN RN=2 AND DATE2< DATE1 AND DATE2>DATE3 THEN 1
                WHEN RN=2 AND DATE2> DATE1 AND DATE2<DATE3 THEN 1
                ELSE 2
                END SAME_ROW_2

         , CASE WHEN RN=3 AND DATE3< DATE1 AND DATE3<DATE2 THEN 0
                WHEN RN=3 AND DATE3< DATE1 AND DATE3>DATE2 THEN 1
                WHEN RN=3 AND DATE3> DATE1 AND DATE3<DATE2 THEN 1
                ELSE 2
                END SAME_ROW_3           
         FROM CTE ORDER BY RN
```